# What could be causing a Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] besides low storage?

Tags: android

I'm an Android developer and today I've started getting this error message when trying to install and run my app. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

I do have problems at times with low storage space on my phone and I get the icon in the notification bar. That's not happening this time though. I've tried deleting several apps and clearing a lot of cache. Currently my phone hasn't been this empty since I first got it.

It's an LG that doesn't allow moving apps to SD though it is rooted and I'm using Link2SD for all of my user apps.

I've read about how android installs a -1 and a -2.apk, I've looked and can't find anything /data/local/tmp/ where it's trying to install to.

My wife has an identical phone which currently shows 177MB available and I'm able to install and run just fine on it. My APK is only 71KB.

Here is my phone's storage state.
[image: Here is my phone's storage state]

What are your thoughts?

Comment: are you trying to reinstall the apk?? from where you are installing the apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your manifest , AndroidManifest.xml will force an app to install to an SD card by doing this.

```
 <android >
        <tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>
        <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

Comment: I've seen that solution, though I hadn't tried it. It did work though. Why would it require this even though my phone has so much more room then my wife's and it worked without this on hers?

Comment: These are usually appear due to low internal storage availability in the device which happens due to installing so many apps because apps use to create file like Caches,Library,etc

Comment: in your case are you using the phone as a test phone??

Comment: Right, but I removed 500MB of data from internal after the first time I got the failure. I use it as my personal phone and for development.

Comment: some times Caches,Library,etc  are keeping the data.If you are interested ,remove the above code and  try with formatting your phone.Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

In the androidManifest.xml, try to add the following:
[`android:installLocation = "preferExternal"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) as below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.nisha.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```